# I have an image's HTTPResponse. How do I display it in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, httpresponse

Currently, I am getting the HTTPRssponse using:

```
def imgResponse(valid_image):
    try:
        with open(valid_image, "rb") as f:
            return HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="image/jpeg")
    except:
        red = Image.new('RGBA', (1, 1), (255,0,0,0))
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
        red.save(response, "JPEG")
        return response
```

I am not sure how to now display this in my HTML template. What I've tried is to pass it in my context:

```
context = {"other_context_part": other_context_part, "my_image": my_image}
```

Then I have the following in my template:

```
{{ my_image }}
```

I am generating this image dynamically and it is not static. How do I display my HTTPResponse?

Comment: To show it in a template it must be served somewhere. You will need to save it somewhere and reference that path on your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def imageResponseView(...)
    ....
    return response

bind url to this view

show image using `<img src = "//url_to_that_view" />`