# Send MySQL blob content as a json response

Tags: python, mysql, json, rest, blob

I have the following code of a GET method which takes a photo which is stored in a blob type field in MySql and return. I want to return it to the client inside a JSON string in a type it can display the image in an angularjs application.

```
 def GET(self,r):
    user_data = CC.get_data(query) # holds the content of the blob field.
    print type(user_data) # prints <type 'str'>
    data = {'name': 'test',
           'photo': user_data}
    return json.dump(data)
```

This gives,

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0:
invalid start byte
```

I have found in some websites its better to send as photo as byte array.
Im using web.py python framework.
whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent data loss, the best thing you can do to send binary data is encode as `base64`.

```
import base64

def GET(self,r):
    user_data = CC.get_data(query) # holds the content of the blob field.
    data = {'name': 'test',
           'photo': base64.b64encode(user_data)}
    return json.dump(data)
```

However, sending binary data over JSON is really not recommended, specially in web. You can send a URL to download the photo, for example.

Comment: thanks it worked. But may I know why sending binary data over JSON is not recommended and letting it to download from a URL?

Comment: It greatly depends on your implementation, but to have your client decode a base64 string may be unnecessary, specially because it can download and display images separately, as most browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

First how to work with blob:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-blob/

To send your image to your template:

def imageResponseView(...) .... return response

bind url to this view

show image using `<img src = "//url_to_that_view" />`

From: [I have an image's HTTPResponse. How do I display it in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727816/i-have-an-images-httpresponse-how-do-i-display-it-in-a-django-template)